# Error : Microsoft Dynamics CRM user exists with the specified domain name and user ID

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am currently stuck on one of the issue of dynamic CRM.

My dynamic CRM application is not running in pre-prod environment and showing message like No Microsoft Dynamics CRM user exists with the specified domain name and user ID.

A few months back, the db cluster failed of this application in pre-prod db server hence I lost database but after that I took database copy from production and restore on pre-production db server, but now my dynamic CRM application is showing message like No Microsoft Dynamics CRM user exists with the specified domain name and user ID.

Maybe it is Active directory related issue not sure cause due to db cluseter failure I took production database into pre-prod db server environment and as of now Pre-prod application is pointing to db which I actually took from production.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore your prod db under different name and then try to import it using deployment manager. During import process you will encounter step when you can map users from db to actual AD logins.